# "I wrote this GitHub action, it almost works, but it fails genearte the report in run-on windows-latest. How solve this issue?

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, github-for-windows, pytest-html

```
-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
- generated html file: ///D:/a/AutomatedTests/automatedTests/%3Dreport.html - -
================== 27 passed, 1 warning in 906.01s (0:15:06) ==================

Using Run-on: windows-latest running successfully and generated the report.
```

```
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/runner/work/AutomatedTests/automatedTests/conftest.py", line 56, in pytest_runtest_makereport
INTERNALERROR>     _capture_screenshot(file_name)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/runner/work/AutomatedTests/automatedTests/conftest.py", line 65, in _capture_screenshot
INTERNALERROR>     driver.get_screenshot_as_file(name)
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screenshot_as_file'

While using with run-on:ubuntu-latest its getting error as above
```

```
import pytest

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

global driver

url="https://automatedtestcases"        


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--browser", action="store", default="firefox"
    )

@pytest.fixture()
def setup(request):
    global driver
    browser = request.config.getoption("browser")

    if browser == "chrome":
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
        from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

    elif browser =="firefox":
        from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
        from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

    print("driver is open 1 ",driver)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    """
        Extends the PyTest Plugin to take and embed screenshot in html report, whenever test fails.
        :param item:
        """
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])

    if report.when == 'call' or report.when == "setup":
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            file_name = report.nodeid.replace("::", "_") + ".png"
            _capture_screenshot(file_name)
            if file_name:
                html = '<div><img src="%s" alt="screenshot" style="width:304px;height:228px;" ' \
                       'onclick="window.open(this.src)" align="right"/></div>' % file_name
                extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html(html))
        report.extra = extra

def _capture_screenshot(name):
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(name)
```

```
name: Automate_testcases_py

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "Automate_with_GitActions" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "Automate_with_GitActions" ]

permissions:
  contents: read
  

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python 3.9
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.9"
    - name: Installing the driver
      run: pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller selenium pyvirtualdisplay      
    
    # Needed to install packages if not installed
    - name: Installing packages
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pytest
        pip install selenium
        pip install pytest-html
        pip install python-dotenv
        pip install webdriver-manager
      
   
    - name: Test with pytest for report
      run: |
        py.test -v -s --html =report.html
```

I have written the workflow file for testcases(selenium with python) and generated the html-report in github actions with RUN-ON : windows-latest (Not in ubuntu-latest). Generated file should open in any branch or should bring out of the git server in order to view that file in same repository (or) different repository.

Need a solution for this problem.Can anyone help me on this

Expecting the solution in run-on:windows-latest

```
If i need to use Run-on: windows-latest. I need to open the generated file into one branch and later it should interact with another repo
(or)
If i need to use Run-on: Ubuntu-latest. I need to solve issue with "Nonetype attribute error".
```

Comment: This isn't a "git action" (Git doesn't have "actions") but rather a "GitHub action". But your question as asked is off-topic for StackOverflow itself. SO is for questions that read more like "I wrote this GitHub action, it almost works, but it fails here with these errors, why?" (and those might involve Git directly, or just pytest itself, or whatever).

Comment: The thing is, you *haven't* written a GitHub action—or if you have, you haven't *shown it to us*. What does it look like? What parts work and what parts don't?

Comment: Hi Torek, Added the github workflow. please look at it and give a solution on generated html-report to store in another branch or a folder

Comment: OK, you now have a Python/or and GitHub-actions question (to which I don't know the answer): why is `driver` still `None` at the call to `_capture_screenshot`? This is probably a pytest-specific question.